# How can I pass kwargs in URL in django

Tags: python, django

In the django doc the url function is like this

```
url(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None, prefix='')
```

I have this

```
url(r'^download/template/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', views.myview().myfunction,model=models.userModel, name="sample")
```

This is my view

```
class myview(TemplateView):

    def myfunction(self,request, object_id, **kwargs):
        model = kwargs['model']
```

I get this error

```
url() got an unexpected keyword argument 'model'
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are trying to pass in a `model` keyword argument to the `url()` function; you need to pass in a `kwargs` argument instead (it takes a dictionary):

```
url(r'^download/template/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', views.myview().myfunction, 
    kwargs=dict(model=models.userModel), name="sample")
```

Comment: @jpic Could you elaborate?

Comment: @buffer: presumably jpic feels [their answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13678956) is the better approach, as there is a thread-safety issue.

Comment: BTW this is how you use itkwargs.pop('name', None)

Comment: @jpic there is no thread safety on the question, so it is a very good answer

Answer (score 8):

This:

```
url(r'^download/template/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', views.myview().myfunction,model=models.userModel, name="sample")
```

Should be:

```
url(r'^download/template/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', views.myview.as_view(model=models.userModel), name="sample")
```

See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/#simple-usage-in-your-urlconf)

Your current implementation is not thread safe. For example:

```
from django import http
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views import generic


class YourView(generic.TemplateView):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = None

    def your_func(self, request, object_id, **kwargs):
        print 'Foo', self.foo
        self.foo = 'bar'
        return http.HttpResponse('foo')



urlpatterns = patterns('test_app.views',
    url(r'^download/template/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', YourView().your_func,
        kwargs=dict(model=User), name="sample"),
)
```

Would you expect it to print 'Foo **None**' ? Well be careful cause the instance is shared across requests:

```
Django version 1.4.2, using settings 'django_test.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Foo None
[03/Dec/2012 08:14:31] "GET /test_app/download/template/3/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3
Foo bar
[03/Dec/2012 08:14:32] "GET /test_app/download/template/3/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3
```

So, when it's not thread safe, you can't assume that it will be in a clean state when the request starts - unlike when using as_view().

Comment: I really don't know how to come at this. i was asking something else. Although i am using generic view but i am calling my custom function

Comment: what u mean by thread safe , i mean what is problem with my view

Comment: I updated my answer to explain the problem with your view. Hope this helps.

Comment: i am new to djnago . i did not understood what is happening. i will tell you. first i don't know what is the meaning of thread safe, then i didn't understand the clean state thing. what topic on internet i need to read to understand that. no matter how much i read , i am always not able to understand the answer given by experienced coder

Comment: i didn't get how r u calling self.foo when u have not declared that attrbute in class

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would have the same functionality (and avoid threading issues) if you did this in your `views.py`

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from .models import userModel

class myview(TemplateView):
    def myfunction(self, request, object_id, *args, **kwargs):
        model = userModel
        # ... Do something with it
```