# Django reverse order of ascending/descending list

Tags: django, django-views

I have a function that gets called from an html file to order my list of books. Upon clicking a button in the html file, book_list_title gets called and I want to reverse the order from either descending to ascending or vice versa but am not sure how to do this.

```
def book_list_title(request):

    if( /* Ordered descending switch to ascending */):
        all_entries = Book.objects.all().order_by('-title')

    else if( /* Ordered in reverse then switch to descending */):
        all_entries = Book.objects.all().order_by('title')

    books_list=[]

    //Do stuff to create a proper list of books

    return render(request,'books_app/books_list.html', {'books_list':books_list})
```

Comment: If you want to show the same items on a list you can reorder that with javascript instead of reloading the page. About the switch, you can use a get request parameter or a kwarg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13678933/how-can-i-pass-kwargs-in-url-in-django

Comment: hmmm I'm not sure i understand entirely what you're saying. How do I know what keyword argument to pass in. Doesn't solve the problem that I am unable to save (and later determine) whether the list is ordered in ascending or descending order

Comment: Why do you need to save it? When you return the list to your view, you include a flag which shows whether it is asc or desc. Your Ajax submit function then sends the opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use addresses like `/books/?order=desc` and `/books/?order=asc`

And in your view handle this flag:

```
def book_list_title(request):
    order = request.GET.get('order', 'desc')

    all_entries = Book.objects.all()

    if(order == 'desc'):
        all_entries = all_entries.order_by('-title')

    elif(order == 'asc'):
        all_entries = all_entries.order_by('title')
```

You can also pass `order` variable into template and depends on it show direction of order in the link

```
{% if order == 'desc' %}/books/?order=asc{% else %}/books/?order=desc{% endif %}
```